# How to embed image placed inside the excel into the .htmlbody of vbascript

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code of the .htmlbody

```
    .htmlBody="<html><center><img src='https://website.com/images/logo-small.png'></center></html>"
```

However, it needs to be downloaded before you can see the logo. So I put the logo inside the excel file, how do I convert it into an shape object and concatenate it inside the .htmlbody

Comment: I believe your src=' needs to be double quotes src="

Comment: No, it's not about the syntax. That's working. I wanted to check out if there are any other way to not use the img src and just get the image inside the excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attachment property of the email to attach the picture to the email.

Then reference the picture in your email with a preceding `.\` like so:

```
 .htmlBody="<html><center><img src='.\logo-small.png'></center></html>"
 .Attachments.Add "C:\yourPath\logo-small.png"
```