# using vba to send a chart in html form through outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am using vba to send a chart in an html formatted email to outlook. The issue is only I am able to see the chart, none of the recipients can view it.

Fname = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart1.jpg"

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("eod summary").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
        Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="JPG"

With OutMail
    .To = "first.lastname@aol.com"
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = h
    .Attachments.Add Fname

    s = "<p><img src=" & Fname & "></p>"
    s = "<HTML><BODY><CENTER>" & s & "</CENTER><HTML><BODY>"

    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & s & RangetoHTML(rng2)

    .Display
    .Send

End With
```

I am saving the file to my temp folder. There is a shared server that the recipients use, however not everyone refers it as the same drive (Z drive for some G drive for others). Therefore, I was unsuccessful when I tried retrieving the image from that filepath.

any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed image placed inside the excel into the .htmlbody of vbascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058862/how-to-embed-image-placed-inside-the-excel-into-the-htmlbody-of-vbascript)

Comment: Thanks Ralph, just to confirm the image has to be attached in order to view the chart within the email?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: no, you could also link to the image and everybody could retrieve the file from a publicly available server. But these images / links get often blocked (as potential spam pixel) by most email clients and the link must be really available to everybody. Yet, this can get sometimes very trick to setup. Especially within large corporations the intranet link (because the internet is partially blocked) is most of the time different to the internet link. There are more things to consider. But that should be all for a small comment to get you going.