# Send tables and graphs via Outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send emails from Excel via Outlook. Within that I have a requirement to send Excel tables and graphs to certain users. The Excel table should be placed after some text provided/written by the sender and should retain the same table format in the email.

I am not able to automate sending the Excel table and graph in the email body.

I am using Excel/Outlook 2010 (Windows).

```vb
Sub Mail_to_MgmtTeam()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Dim rng As Range

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim total_Resource As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Delete the Temp sheets, if any (just precautionary step)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"

Sheets("Mail Details").Select
Range("A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Temp").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

'' Below code not getting executed successfully
'Selection.Select
'Set rng = Sheets("Temp").Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'rng.Copy

' NEED HELP Here : TO send this selected TABLE within the email BODY to someone...

' code for sending the mails form Excel
Sheets("Mail Details").Select
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Dear " & Cells(x + 5, 3).Value & ", " & _
       vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
       "Below Table provides the overall statue of Pending Lists." & _
         vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Thank You " & vbNewLine & "XYZ..."
    
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Sheets("Mail Details").Range("D6").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Excel Table Attached"
    .Body = strbody
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Mails have been sent", vbDefaultButton1, "Mail Sent!!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think CopyAsPicture or Image, not sure will help.

Comment: This is a very compounded question including (1) export of charts to images (2) export tables to images (3) attach images to emails (4) format emails (probably using HTML (5)). So, I'd recommend that you break down your question into several posts. Yet, to at least some of the afore mentioned there are many answers already to be found on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939087/export-chart-as-image-with-click-of-a-button OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058862/how-to-embed-image-placed-inside-the-excel-into-the-htmlbody-of-vbascript/36060411#36060411

Comment: @ Ralph... Ok will do that and thanks for the links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to complete the task for which i had posted. I am posting the final code below for anyone who may need help in future on the similar line...

PS:

- I have segmented into different sets for easy of use. Please copy each code and paste it in in 'module' back to back
- The sheet name should be "RawData" and "ReportData"
- The Table should be placed in sheet "RawData"  and Column header should be in Row 5
- In sheet "RawData", in K Column, Mail ID is mentioned

Macro #1

```
Option Explicit
Dim folder_path As String
Dim chart_no As Integer
Dim file_path As String

Sub mail_2_IBUhead()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim total_Resource As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("RawData").Select

Call export_chart

Call Send_Automate_Mail

Sheets("RawData").Select
Range("A1").Select

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill file_path & "Chart_1.png"

MsgBox "Draft Mails have been generated", vbDefaultButton1, "Mail Drafted!!!"


End Sub
```

Macro #2:

```
Private Sub Send_Automate_Mail()
' This macro would only send the mail...

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody_1 As String, strbody_2 As String, strbody_3 As String
Dim Start_row As Integer, Start_column As Integer, End_row As Integer, End_Column As Integer

' selecting the entire table range in the sheet
Sheets("RawData").Select
Range("A5").Select
Start_row = Selection.Row
Start_column = Selection.Column
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
End_Column = Selection.Column
Range("A5").End(xlDown).Select
End_row = Selection.Row

Range(Cells(Start_row, 1), Cells(End_row, End_Column)).Select

Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


strbody_1 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear User,<p>" & _
            " Below is the Graph.... <br> </BODY> "

strbody_2 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
            " Below is the Table... <br> </BODY> "

strbody_3 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri> This is an Automated mail. Please do not respond. <p> <p> " & _
            " Regards, <br> Sender </BODY> "

file_path = folder_path & "\"

With OutMail
    .To = Sheets("RawData").Range("k6").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "BE. RawData"
    .Attachments.Add file_path & "Chart_1.png"
    .htmlbody = strbody_1 & "<p>" & "<p>" & _
                "<img src='cid:Chart_1.png'" & "width='1000' height='580'>" & "<br>" & "<p>" & _
                strbody_2 & "<p>" & _
                RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & _
                strbody_3
    .Importance = 2
    ' display the e-mail message, change it to ".send" to send the mail on running the macro
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Macro #3:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' this function is used in code "Send_Automate_Mail"
' do not change the code if you are new to coding :)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Macro #4:

```
Private Sub export_chart()
' this code will export all the graphs present in the sheet

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim x As Integer

folder_path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

' for each graph present in the sheet, it will get exported
Sheets("ReportData").Select
x = 1
For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    objCht.Chart.Export folder_path & "\Chart_" & x & ".png", "PNG"
    x = x + 1
Next objCht

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Kunal...